# How do I reset a NSLevelIndicatorCell to 0?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSLevelIndicatorCell embedded as a column in a TableView using Core Data / Bindings.  This works fine, but I'm looking for a way to "reset" the LevelIndicator to 0 (no stars selected.)  This would preferably happen when the user double clicks on the level indicator or clicks on the single selected star when its selected (ie, to unselect it.)  This doesn't appear to be supported behavior for the indicator.  I'm new to Cocoa and looking for guidance on how to extend this behavior.  For instance, should I subclass NSLevelIndicatorCell for this behavior or is it something I should do with an IBOutlet to the tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is already built in: Click a star and drag to the left of the first star.